# Debugging in VS

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-debugging

Recently I noticed some strange behavior when debugging ASP.NET application. When I press F10,  sometimes it doesn't go to the next code line, but just stays on the same until you press it 2-3 times. And sometimes it goes to the previous line. It happens only in one library, used for this application, all other code I can debug as usual. Is it some kind of bug? Can it be fixed?

Comment: yes, maybe you're right. I see Tread dropdown when I debugging and it's active when I'm in this library. And I see it's changing when cursor is staying on the same line.

Comment: Btw, how can I see that this code is multithreading?

Comment: You don't know whether the code you are using is doing multithreading? Wow, that's alarming! I would probably start with learning what the code I am using is doing. Otherwise I might do some harm without even realizing.

Comment: This application consists from many parts and of course I don't know all code. I know only part with which I'm currently working. I just started to debug this library to find one bug.

Comment: Well, then what is your question? There's no bug in Visual Studio debugger that I am aware of exhibiting the behavior you are experiencing. If the code you are calling is multithreaded it could be perfectly normal to get this behavior.

Comment: So, question is answered. This now I know that this is not bug, but normal behavior. I don't have much of experience with multithreading, so now I'll look how to deal with it.
If you write the same as an answer, I'll mark it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a bug in Visual Studio Debugger but probably a standard behavior that is resulting from calling a multithreaded code.